# .class syntax breaks for generics

Tags: java, class, object, generics

I have the following method:

```
public <T> T get(String property, Class<T> expectedClass) {...}
```

When I try to class it with a generic class in place of `T`, I can't get the class object using the `.class` syntax (as in `ArrayList<Object>.class`). Isn't Java suppose to reduce the generic to a normal class and, therefor, shouldn't there be some way to get the .class object?

This is the actual method call:

```
itemSource = (Collection<Item<SourceIdentifierType>>) configuration.get("initial items", KeyCollection<Item<SourceIdentifierType>>.class);
```

Comment: Think about this for a moment. The same `Class` object exists for `KeyCollection` as for `KeyCollection<RandomType>`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Thanks, but that's not intuitive to me. As I mentioned, type erasure would make you think they got assigned different classes.

Comment: On the contrary, type erasure means they are the exact same thing. Except your syntax is wrong.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis My understanding, which seems to be flawed, was that type erasure effectively generated a new class in bytecode for each type parameter.

Comment: @sinθ That does happens in C++ I guess, but not in Java.

Comment: Type erasure, as the name suggest, erases the generic type. At run time, you have no idea what that type is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java Language Specification says the following about [class literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2)

> A class literal is an expression consisting of the name of a class,
>   interface, array, or primitive type, or the pseudo-type void, followed
>   by a '.' and the token class.
>
> The type of C.class, where C is the name of a class, interface, or
>   array type (§4.3), is Class.
>
> [...]
>
> It is a compile-time error if the named type is a type variable (§4.4)
>   or a parameterized type (§4.5) or an array whose element type is a
>   type variable or parameterized type.

You cannot do that.

What you can do, but you'll have to refactor heavily, is to use [type tokens](http://gafter.blogspot.ca/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html).

Comment: I couldn't understand how type tokens will be used here. Can you elaborate, perhaps with an example?

Comment: @RohitJain I would love to, but I don't know exactly what OP is trying to accomplish. The best example I have is how [Gson](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#fromJson(com.google.gson.JsonElement,java.lang.reflect.Type)) uses it to parse JSON, for a `List<Foo>` for example. Through the type token, it can determine it should return a `List` containing `Foo` objects. As such, it parses the JSON as an array containing `Foo` instances.

Comment: Yes, OP code is actually confusing. From what I understand, he might be trying to write `get` method to get all properties for an object. But then he should have `T` as second parameter instead of `Class<T>`, but alas, OP didn't told us what he's trying to do :)

Comment: a very noob question indeed,what is OP?

Comment: @AbhinavKumar Opening (or Original) post (or poster).